# how to create instance of class with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am a beginner in writing tests and in jest also. I want to test that this function to be called and return the success promise. I write a unit test for function using jest. The function gets like parameter instance of class that I can't create because its constructor requires parameters that I haven't access. I have a lot of functions that have Session like parametrs. How can test function when you cant provide parametrs for it? Can I mock instance of class or function and handle it without parameter?

```
async initFlow(session: Session) {
    const nextAtomId = session.userInput.getParam('NEXT_ATOM');
    if (nextAtomId) {
        const nextAtom = await AtomManager.findActiveAtom(nextAtomId);
        if (!session.features.useTerms || ['beforeTerms', 'TermsAndConditions'].includes(nextAtom.type)) {
            return AtomProcessor.processAtom(session, nextAtom);
        }
    }

    const start = await AtomManager.getStartAtom(`${session.botId}`);
    if (!start) {
        throw new Error('Could not find start atom');
    }

    session.user = await UserManager.getGlobalUser(session); // getGlobalUser makes initUser under the hood.
    return AtomProcessor.processAtom(session, start);
}
```

Comment: You wish to test the `initFlow` function? If so, what exactly do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test that this function to be called and return the success promise.

Comment: Did you check the answer below, was it helpful?

Comment: Your answer helped me understand how to work mock, but I faced another problem, I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328959/jest-called-chain-of-imported-dependencies-of-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock both `AtomManager` & `UserManager` and provide a mock session object when calling `initFlow`.

```
jest.mock("./path/to/AtomManager");
jest.mock("./path/to/UserManager");

it("works", async () => {
  const mockSession = {
    userInput: {
      getParam: jest.fn(),
    },
    botId: "123",
  };
  const mockUser = "user123";
  const mockStartAtom = "atom123";
  AtomManager.getStartAtom.mockResolveValue(mockStartAtom);
  UserManager.getGlobalUser.mockResolveValue(mockUser);

  await initFlow(mockSession);

  expect(mockSession.user).toBe(mockUser);
  expect(AtomManager.getStartAtom).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(AtomManager.getStartAtom).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockSession.botId);
  expect(UserManager.getGlobalUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(UserManager.getGlobalUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockSession);
  expect(AtomProcessor.processAtom).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(AtomProcessor.processAtom).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockSession, mockStartAtom);
});
```

The snippet above makes the following assertions:

1. `AtomManager.getStartAtom` is called once and it's called with the mock `botId`.
2. `UserManager.getGlobalUser` is called once and it's called with the mock session object.
3. `UserManager.getGlobalUser` has successfully added the `user` property on the passed session object.
4. `AtomProcessor.processAtom` is called once and it's called with the mock session and the mock start atom.

You can similarly the test other branches of code.